# Full Calendar Width

Tags: wordpress, calendar

I am currently using the Calendar on a wordpess website with restricted width on the page due to widgets restricting width on the right hand side.

This is causing the events to be squashed up in the week view, can I :

Disable the Sunday day so that the other 6 days are wider

Can I make each day wider and use a scroll bar along the bottom for the week view ?

Are these two options possible ? If so how can I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Sunday is probably possible, although I haven't done it before and I can bet you it's going to require extensive php coding to achieve.

The easiest, to my mind, would be to play around with the CSS of the calendar widget. Here's my suggestions:

1. You could make each day (which'll be
   an `<li>` tag) wider;
2. Give that widget a set width /
   height; and lastly
3. Set the parent (either the tag, or
   the containing tag) CSS to
   `overflow: scroll`.

It won't be pretty (unless you use Javascript/jQuery), but it'll work...

Hope it helps...